# How do I append state to an array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to append a props.addremoveDatabase state variable(from a different component hence why props is used) to the end of the newState array. However this is not working and I am not to sure why as I have tried using the push method to do so.

Error:

[image]

```
const [addRemoveDatabase, setAddRemoveDatabase] = useState([
  'iadcaprod.auiag.corp/iadpprod',
]);
const [productionDatabaseData, setProductionDatabaseData] = useState([]);
const addToProduction = ({target}, {id, databases}) => {
  setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {
    let newState = [...previousState];
    if (target.checked) {
      newState = [
        ...newState,
        {unit_test_id: id, databases: databases.push(props.addRemoveDatabase)},
      ];
    } else {
      const i = newState.findIndex(({unit_test_id}) => unit_test_id === id);
      if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1);
    }

    return newState;
  });
};
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, you use objects. Right?

```
databases.push(props.addRemoveDatabase)
newState = [
  ...newState,
  {unit_test_id: id, databases: [...databases]},
];
```

Comment: Yep that is correct, seems to be working however. It is only returning the length when I tried that code? I just updated my answer so you can see

Comment: still wrong databases.push(props.addRemoveDatabase)

Comment: In my answer, I change it to databases: databases.push(props.addRemoveDatabase)

Comment: Yes, I changed it but its returning the length back not the array name

Comment: Updated my answer